# How can I change the culture for CMS Desk

Tags: content-management-system, kentico

I would like the dates in CMS Desk (e.g. User Created date) to be in UK culture. I don't want to change the site itself (US Culture).

Is this possible and if so how can it be done.

I'm using Kentico v9.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change the user preferred language settings. This can be done in the user menu (upper right corner):

[image: User menu]

or in the users application:

[image: Users application]

If the required language is missing, open the Localization application, find the missing culture, edit it and tick the Is UI culture checkbox:

[image]

Now you'll be able to select it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't change culture just partially. You may try to play around with Default content culture and Visitor culture under sites.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Kentico Documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Changing+the+date+and+time+format) Inside the administration interface, the date and time format depends on the preferred user interface culture of each user